# Web Service EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, web-services

When i try to retrieve data from db i get this exception.

Host web.config file and in code i open listener.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="NORTHWIND" connectionString="Data Source=LP\SQLEXPRESS; 
  Initial Catalog=NORTHWND; Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyService.MyService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8090/MyService/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="NORTHWIND" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        contract="MyService.IMyService">         
    </endpoint>
  </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Client code.

```
private void ReadAllBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Uri httpAddress = new 
Uri("http://localhost:8090/MyService/NORTHWIND");
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(httpAddress);

        IMyService proxy = ChannelFactory<IMyService>.CreateChannel(new 
BasicHttpBinding(), endpoint);
        dataGridView.DataSource = proxy.ReadPerson();

    }
```

Does someone knows what can be the problem?